Hamiltonian of the Ablowitz-Ladik NLS
The Ablowitz-Ladik nonlinear Schrodinger equation is written
\begin{equation}i\frac{d}{dt}\psi_j = -\psi_{j+1}+2\psi_{j}-\psi_{j-1}+|\psi_j|^2(\psi_{j+1} + \psi_{-1})\end{equation}
where the wavefunction $\psi_j \in \mathbb{C}$ is complex and $j \in \mathbb{Z}$.
Per https://arxiv.org/pdf/2107.04866 section $2$, the Hamiltonian of this system is defined under a weighted Poisson bracket:
\begin{equation}H = -\sum_{j=0}^{N-1}\psi_{j-1}\psi_j^{\ast} + \psi_{j-1}^{\ast}\psi_j,\end{equation}
where the Poisson-bracket is written $\{A,B\}=i\sum_{j=0}^{N-1}\left (\frac{\partial A}{\partial \psi_j^{\ast}}\frac{\partial B}{\partial \psi_j}-\frac{\partial A}{\partial \psi_j}\frac{\partial B}{\partial \psi_j^{\ast}}\right)(1 - |\psi_j|^2)$
Question: How is this form equivalent to $i\dot{\psi}_j = \frac{\partial H}{\partial \psi_j^{\ast}}$? Since the nonlinearity is not included in the definition of $H$, how could this be equivalent even though it is supposed to be?

It isn't, indeed. What makes you believe so ? The paper you linked doesn't seem to claim this equivalence (although I haven't read it extensively).

I had always thought they were equivalent ways of describing the system. Further, the Hamiltonian is supposed to describe the energy of the wave. If $H$ does not include the nonlinearity, how can properly describe the energy?

@Abezhiko I think your comment satisfies my question as an Answer. Please, if you would like, add your comment as an Answer and it will be accepted. Perhaps an added example worked out for the bracket yielding equations of motion.

Done, take a look ! And glad to help ;)

1° The Hamiltonian might be interpreted as the energy of the system in many cases, but it isn't required ultimately; it shall be seen as a "state function", which describes a system by generating the related equations of motion through a given recipe $-$ in the same way as the thermodynamical potentials do in a different context.
2° If a Poisson bracket has been defined, then it generates the equations of motions through the relation $\dot{\psi} = -i\{H,\psi\}$ (which is not equivalent to $\frac{\partial H}{\partial\psi^*}$ in general). For example, with the Poisson bracket and the Hamiltonian defined in your post, we have :
$$
\begin{align}
\dot{\psi}_j 
   &= -i\{H,\psi_j\} \\
   &= \sum_k \left(\frac{\partial H}{\partial\psi_k^*}\frac{\partial\psi_j}{\partial\psi_k} - \frac{\partial\psi_j}{\partial\psi_k^*}\frac{\partial H}{\partial\psi_j}\right) (1-|\psi_k|^2) \\
   &= (1-|\psi_j|^2)\frac{\partial H}{\partial\psi_j^*} \\
   &= -(1-|\psi_j|^2)\frac{\partial}{\partial\psi_j^*} \sum_k (\psi_{k-1}\psi_k^* + \psi_{k-1}^*\psi_k) \\
   &= -(1-|\psi_j|^2)(\psi_{j-1}+\psi_{j+1})
\end{align}
$$
where we used the facts that $\frac{\partial\psi_\mu}{\partial\psi_\nu} = \frac{\partial\psi_\mu^*}{\partial\psi_\nu^*} = \delta_{\mu\nu}$ and $\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial\psi^*} = \frac{\partial\psi^*}{\partial\psi} = 0$. This result corresponds to  the equation of motion $(2.6)$ in the paper you linked.
N.B. : the term $2\psi_j$ is absent, because the Poisson brackets have been defined after the change of variable $\alpha_j = \psi_je^{-2it}$, the latter being responsible for the "absorption" of the said term.

When $H$ is defined under such a weighted bracket, is it possible to recover the form of $H$ for when the dynamics is described by $\frac{\partial H}{\partial \psi_j^{\ast}}$?

@KZ-Spectra.   Then you need a new Hamiltonian, such as
$$
\tilde{H} = H + \frac{1}{2}\sum_k \psi_k^*|\psi_k|^2(\psi_{k-1}+\psi_{k+1}).
$$
Nonetheless, I'm not sure it is possible to construct a hermitian Hamiltonian in that case.

I thought Hermitian was a property of matrices. What would it mean here? And why is it desired?

@KZ-Spectra. It would be equivalent to a real Hamiltonian in the present case, but here $\tilde{H}^* \neq \tilde{H}$. Hamiltonians needn't be hermitian, but it is a commonly wanted property, depending on what is done next.

Since you were helpful with this question, I wrote a related question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4965853/597047 here.
